# Make tags cs.fl.formal-languages and formal-language-theory synonyms of fl.formal-languages

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request, tag-synonyms

Currently the tag [formal-language-theory](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formal-language-theory) is a synonym for the tag [cs.fl.formal-languages](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cs.fl.formal-languages), but the tag actually used for questions in formal language theory is [fl.formal-languages](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fl.formal-languages).  Therefore, please do the following:

- Change [formal-language-theory](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formal-language-theory) from a synonym for [cs.fl.formal-languages](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cs.fl.formal-languages) to a synonym for [fl.formal-languages](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fl.formal-languages).
- Make [cs.fl.formal-languages](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cs.fl.formal-languages) a synonym for [fl.formal-languages](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fl.formal-languages).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been done.  Thanks, Suresh.